# restarting geth causing loss of data

Tags: ubuntu, blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle, go-ethereum

What I want is stopping geth, changing some parameters in genesis.json file like gasLimit, then resuming geth without loosing data that was previously added by smart contracts.

These are the steps:

```
killall geth geth --datadir ./myDataDir init ./myGenesis.json 
cp -r /var/keystore myDataDir/ 
geth --datadir ./myDataDir --rpc --networkid 1441 console 2>> myEth.log
miner.start()
personal.unlockAccount(personal.listAccounts[0], "xxxxxxxxxxxx", 0)
```

I know executing **init** will reinitiate it, but if I dont run this command I will have conflict of addresses when i deploy my code using truffle deploy.

So how can I restart go-ethereum (geth) in this case without losing data?